# Importing Python module error

Tags: python, importerror

I'm trying to run a program called Sansview with the module sansview.py.

I currently get this error:

[image: Import error]

The directory where the gui_manager.py is located is:
"C:\sansviewproject\trunk\build\lib.win32-2.6\sans\guiframe"

The directory where the sansview.py is located is:
"C:\sansviewproject\trunk\build\lib.win32-2.6\sans\sansview"

I believed the problem had something to do with having the wrong environmental variables set. However I currently have PYTHONPATH set to: 
"C:\Python26;C:\sansviewproject\trunk\build" which should pick up the gui_manager.py module.

I am running python 2.6 on Win7. If anyone could point me in the right direction of where my error could be I would appreciate it.

Comment: I think that your path should include `C:\sansviewproject\trunk\build\lib.win32-2.6`, as you'd want the `sans` module to be available in the first place.

Comment: Try setting your PYTHONPATH to `C:\sansviewproject\trunk\build\lib.win32-2.6` instead.

Comment: Don't forget to accept an answer by clicking on the green checkmark by it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have a directory on your PYTHONPATH which contains the "sans" package for "from sans.guiframe import gui_manager" to work.
So I guess it would be:

```
C:\Python26;C:\sansviewproject\trunk\build\lib.win32-2.6
```

rather than just:

```
C:\Python26;C:\sansviewproject\trunk\build
```

which needs to be there.

Hope this helps.